# Dirac Notation: Why are these two expressions equal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

Consider 
$$
\langle a''|(AB - BA)|a' \rangle  =  (a'' - a') \langle a''|B|a' \rangle
$$
where $a''$ and $a'$ are eigenvalues of observable, $A$, which is Hermitian (real eigenvalues). $A$ and $B$ are compatible observables. Also, the eigenvalues of $A$ are nondegenerate.

This equation is from *Modern Quantum Mechanics* by Sakurai and Napolitano (page 29).

So far, I have:

$$ = \langle a''|AB - BA|a'\rangle = \langle a''|a''B - Ba'|a' \rangle = \langle a''|(a'' - a')B|a'\rangle = (a'' - a') \langle a''|B|a'\rangle$$

But I am not sure if it is okay to take away the parentheses surrounding $(AB-BA)$ so that I can "split" the operator in the middle.

Comment: This follows immediately from the definition of an eigenvector

Comment: OP is asking about the parentheses, which appear to be gratuitous, so a careful mind would ask whether they can be ignored in a new context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses are needed.

With parentheses:

$$
\langle a''|(AB - BA)|a' \rangle  = \langle a''|AB|a'\rangle- \langle a'' |BA|a' \rangle  =  \langle a'' | a'' B | a' \rangle- \langle a''|B a' | a'\rangle =  (a''-a') \langle a'' | B | a' \rangle
$$

without:

$$
\langle a''|AB - BA|a' \rangle  = \langle a''| a'' B- B a'|a' \rangle  =  a'' \langle a '' | B -a'B|a'\rangle
$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the parenthesis is not an operator but a number which can be taken out.

Comment: I think he is referring to the parentheses around (AB-BA).

Comment: Right. The parenthesis there is for convenience. Can be done away with.

Comment: Valerios answer is correct. I coudnt explain my point due to lack of my expertise in writing down these equations on this background.

Comment: Hope to learn this art is future.